# Reading File function in python

Tags: python

hello I am trying to apply the file reading function in python

```
f = open("C:\\Users\\hamza\\Desktop\\family.txt","r")
print(f.read())
```

It keeps giving me the error of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    f = open("C:\\Users\\hamza\\Desktop\\family.txt","r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\hamza\\Desktop\\family.txt'
```

please help me to resolve this issue

Thankyou

Comment: The error indicates that the file you are trying to open does not exist. Are you sure it is there?

Comment: What Heike said. Double-check the path, name, and extension.

Comment: yes, its in my desktop. I have looked at it a few times and was keep trying again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct code to read a file. `C:\\Users\\hamza\\Desktop\\family.txt"` must not exist.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try following code also,

   ```
   path="C:\\Users\\hamza\\Desktop\\family.txt"
   f = open(path,"r")
   print(f.read())
   ```

   But your code is also correct.
2. Please check if file is present on desktop and name of file is correct or not

Comment: It exists in my desktop, I have confirmed few times, but it was still giving me the same error

Comment: First try to open a file in same folder as of your program. Then go for file at different location.I would suggest you to change the location and name of file and then try.